# How to query for boolean values in dynamo DB

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, dynamodb-queries

```
response = cls.table_advisor_settings.query(
            IndexName = "complete_compliance_status-index",
            KeyConditionExpression=Key("complete_compliance_status").eq(False))
```

When I am trying to maoke query in DynamoDb I am Getting below error :

```
botocore.exceptions.ClientError: An error occurred (ValidationException) when calling the Query operation: One or more parameter values were invalid: Condition parameter type does not match schema type
```

In DynamoDB "complete_compliance_status" has boolean value.

Comment: also when i am adding index in there are only three data type available for attribute type Sting, Integer, Binary

Comment: `KeyConditionExpression` is for (primary) key fields. The Boolean `complete_compliance_status` CANNOT be one of the  index's key fields, because [only String, Number and Binary types can be used in key fields](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/HowItWorks.CoreComponents.html#HowItWorks.CoreComponents.PrimaryKey).  What one or two fields make up the the [index's primary key](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/SecondaryIndexes.html)?